# React JS, Spring and Postgres project

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, postgresql

For my project, I am building a fitness app with React front-end and Spring back-end. DB I am using is Postgres.
I have completed my back-end set up which includes all my controllers.
My front-end is supposed to be have a landing page which displays a list of all muscles. I have got that by writing the following code:

```
    const renderedMuscles = muscles.map((muscle) =>{
        return <MuscleCard muscle={muscle} key={muscle.id}/>
    });
```

I am then returning {renderedMuscles} which generates a list of muscle items.
I am now stuck on the following:

1. I want to click on a muscle item and then fetch exercises for the clicked muscle from the DB. For example, clicking on 'chest' should return a list that includes 'bench press', 'dumbbell flies', 'press ups' etc.
2. I then want to click on an exercise which brings up a form that has an increment and decrement button for reps, and increment and decrement button for weight and a save button.

How do I progress with this? My instructor suggested that I may have to use react controllers instead of Spring but other than that he doesn't know how I can achieve this or what I can do next. If I create a React router, what is it that I can achieve with it that I can't with my current set up?
I am more than half-way through my project and I feel I am really close to completion but really frustrated with what I am stuck on. Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think that your question is very broad, but aside from that, it would benefit from you giving some code from your API and some idea of how is your database modelled.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.